# How to get the right radio button checked in Android?

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I am working on my project and I have to store the gender of customer in a database. I have used radio buttons to obtain the input by the user. But whatever I do, only data I am getting is female. I have used onCheckChanged and taken help of string buffer but the only thing it appends is female.

```
 db.execSQL("INSERT INTO students Values('" + EditCustomerID.getText() + "','" + EditCustomerName.getText() + "','" + EditDressID.getText()
                + "','" + EditAddress.getText() + "','" + EditPhoneNumber.getText() + "','"+rb.toString()  +"');");
        showMessage("Success", "Record added");

public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    if (checkedId==R.id.radioButton1){
        rb.append("Male");
    }
    else{
        rb.append("Female");
    }
}
```

In XML I have introduced radio buttons with following Id's,

```
<RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_x="150dp"
            android:layout_y="300dp" >
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/male"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/female"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                />

        </RadioGroup>
```

And this is where I have used cursor.

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            EditCustomerName.setText(c.getString(1));
            EditDressID.setText(c.getString(2));
            EditAddress.setText(c.getString(3));
            EditPhoneNumber.setText(c.getString(4));
            if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()==male.getId()){
                radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButton1);
            }
            else{
                radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButton2);
            }

        }
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that problem lies within your cursor. I don't see you getting any value about gender from database. I assume you are setting values from database, so it should be

```
if (c.getString(5).equals("Male") {
     radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButton1);
} else {
     radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButton2);
}
```

Feel free to comment my answer, I will improve it when you give more details / edit your question with more code etc.

Comment: Yes the values are being set from the database but with the code you provided the result stayed the same.
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO students Values('" + EditCustomerID.getText() + "','" + EditCustomerName.getText() + "','" + EditDressID.getText()
                    + "','" + EditAddress.getText() + "','" + EditPhoneNumber.getText() + "','"+rb.toString()  +"');");
            showMessage("Success", "Record added");
This is where I added data in the database.

Comment: @WajahatIqbal Did you try debug your line `db.execSQL()` and set watcher to check what is being added as `rb.toString()`?